# How to set custom color to leaflet ExtraMarkers

Tags: colors, leaflet

I am using leaflet [ExtraMarkers](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers) and I would like to set custom color. It should be possible by svg.

this is my definition of marker icon:

```
            var coloredMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
                svg: true,
                markerColor: "#66ff33",
            });
```

and marker:

```
var marker= new L.marker([latitude,longitude], {icon: coloredMarker}).addTo(map);
```

But result is that color of marker is default - red

Can you help?

Comment: well, there is no `svg` property in `IconOptions` defined by `ExtraMarkers`...

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers#properties) that the only markerColor valid values are :
`'red', 'orange-dark', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue-dark', 'cyan', 'purple', 'violet', 'pink', 'green-dark', 'green', 'green-light', 'black', or 'white'`

Those possible values are css class defined by the ExtraMarkers plugin. If you set `markerColor` to a color value, it does not correspond to any css class.

To set custom colors, i guess you could try to modify ExtraMarkers code but it might be difficult. The markers are all in one image. The plugin chooses one by displaying just a part of this image.

Comment: I guess what you mean is that it is possible to choose a color when displaying a svg in a web page. Well maybe, but here, the ExtraMarkers readme is pretty explicit on valid values and the source code just picks an existing css class corresponding to the color name to cut the markers image.